# How do I check if a string contains at least some specific characters?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, character

I would like to check if a string contains at least some of the characters in a list of characters.

The bottom line of the question is that I would like to recognize a string also if it contains a typo.

For example if I need to recognize the string *"I like cats"* I would do something simple like:

```
if "i like cats" in string.lower():
    '''do stuff'''
```

or maybe something like:

```
charactersToMatch = ['ilikecats ']
if all(c in charactersToMatch for c in string):
    '''do stuff'''
```

I am aware that using the second example could lead to recognizing also a string like *"cats likess i"*, and I'm fine with it.
For me it's enough if just 9 of the 10 characters in `charactersToMatch` are contained in the string. In order to be able to recognize also strings like *"i lije cats"* or *"i like catz"*
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Apply Levenstein distance algorithm

Comment: Thank you very much! It suits perfectly for what I need!